# Как в python изменять цвет текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Я попробовал использовать \033[91m, но часть [91m выводится на экран.
Что делать?

Comment: У тебя windows?

Comment: Если Windows, то нужно использовать colorama. Терминал Windows "из-коробки" не поддерживает изменение цвета через ASCII последовательности.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь более подробно – [How to print colored text in terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python)

```
class Bcolors:
    FAIL = '\033[91m'

print(f"{Bcolors.FAIL}Warning: No active frommets remain. Continue?")

# Warning: No active frommets remain. Continue? <-- вывод в красном цвете
```